# yeoman and grunt are not packaging some css files

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I used [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) to start an angular projects.
I used bower to install some angular components.

In my index.html I have this peace of code

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
  <!--should be the last to override-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/diverse.css">
</head>
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/hello/dist/hello.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```

after I run

```
grunt serve:dist
```

the index.html get compiled and here is the result.

```
    <!doctype html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>indexPage</title> 
<meta name="description" content=""> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"> <!--to auto host later--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css"> <!--should be the last to override--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/custom2.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/diverse.css"> </head> 
<script src="scripts/vendor.3bff2419.js"></script> <script src="scripts/scripts.c4d1c5ee.js"></script> <body ng-app="frontApp" ng-class="body_style"> <!--<div ng-show="mainNavBar_show" ng-include src="mainNavBar"></div>--> <div ng-view></div> </body> </html>
```

All the files that are shown as link rel="..." 
are throwing 404 error. ( not the case for the files that are succeffully compiled)

here is screenshot from the error code.
How can i make grunt add this files.
I used the defaukt [grunt.js](https://github.com/toumiGit/privateGit/blob/master/gruntfile.js) shipped with yeoman.

[image]

Comment: post your grunt tasks for creating your "build"

Comment: i have edited my post and added the gruntFile.js

Comment: which yeoman generator are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your HTML has been rewritten to point the DIST folder which is something that "makes sense", a solution could be to make a copy of your bower components to your DIST folder or change the rewriting html rules in your grunt tasks.

I use a copy grunt task like this one

```
copy: {
            main: {
                files: [
                    { src: ['**/**.min.css'], dest: 'dist/' },
                    { src: ['bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**'], dest: 'dist/' },
                    { src: ['bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.min.**'], dest: 'dist/' },
                    { src: ['bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.**'], dest: 'dist/' },
                    { src: ['bower_components/angular/angular.min.**'], dest: 'dist/' },
                    { src: ['bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_es-419.min.**'], dest: 'dist/' },
                    //... and so on...

               ]
            }
        }
```

Comment: sould I delete copy: {
      tmp: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/fixtures',
          src: ['usemin.html', 'usemin/*'],
          dest: 'tmp/'
        }]
      }   or do i have to concat both

Comment: seems like that step is for doing other processes later, that's probably for compress / optimize js files, so I don't think delete the step is a good option, try to add the additional steps to copy the files in your DIST folder

Comment: did you double check, the files in your dist folder?

Comment: i cannot check anything in my dist folder, it is a compiled and minified files

Comment: I mean if the libraries are physically  in dist/bower_components/linbrary-name?

Comment: ah yes sure. because when i run grunt serve ( which run the uncompiled version), it works